# binding a bootstrap list-group to a knockout ko.observable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Is it possible to bind a `ko.observable` to a bootstrap `list-group`? 
any libraries that could help achiving such thing or is it possible to do with them javascript without using anyother libraries?

Comment: Are you talking about this list-group: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group? Because there is no js needed here only some css classes what you can easily generate with kncokout...

Comment: @nemesv more specifically the one with Custom content

Comment: I still don't see what problems do you have with generating this very simple html structure... http://jsfiddle.net/7qfTK/

Comment: @nemesv i was missing the foreach, please add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use a simple `foreach` binding to generate the required HTML for the list-items of the [bootstrap list-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group), and you can use the `css` and the `click` binding to track the selected item.

Your view should look like this:

```
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: items">  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="
         css: { active: $parent.selectedItem() == $data}, 
         click: $parent.select.bind($parent)">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-bind="text: header"></h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text" data-bind="text: text"></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

And your in view model, you can bind it to an `ko.observableArray`:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    selectedItem: ko.observable(),
    items: ko.observableArray([
        {header: 'header 1', text: "Cras justo odio"},
        {header: 'header 2', text: "Dapibus ac facilisis in"},
        {header: 'header 3', text: "Morbi leo risus"},
        {header: 'header 4', text: "Porta ac consectetur ac"},
        {header: 'header 5', text: "Vestibulum at eros"}
    ]),
    select: function(item){
        this.selectedItem(item);
    }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qfTK/).